# How to display a C# using() statement in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Is there a rule/guideline about how to display a C# using() statement in UML sequence diagrams?

I'm right now in the last months of my apprenticeship. And to
prove, that I'm able to develop software from start to beginning, I
have to do a project which has to have a documentation. This
documentation will be shown to a jury to rate it.

My thought was to create an activation adding a note to it, saying `using(CmSdkScope scope = new CmSdkScope)`, and then adding another activation - like a self call - to it, where I then message other classes.

Here is an example:
[image]

Is this valid?

Comment: Why... I mean, if you’re going to write code, go write code.

Comment: Because I need to create documentation? I'd love to just write code...

Comment: Code is documentation. Create those uml diagrams from from code. It's madness to try and create them by hand before you actually write your code.

Comment: Maybe I'll do that afterwards. But I'm also trying to improve myself. To get a better overview about how my application is going to work.

Comment: In that case, create whatever diagrams you need to help you understand how your design might work. Since they are for you, do not worry about "proper" UML; draw whatever what makes sense to you. Then throw those diagrams away before you start coding, please.

Comment: Sorry, no non-programmer knows what the hell this means. Any programmer will just go look for themselves.

Comment: Okay, a bit more information to why I have to create this sequence diagram: I'm right now in the last months of my apprenticeship. And to prove, that I'm able to develop software from start to beginning, I have to do a project which has to have a documentation. This documentation will be shown to a jury to rate it.

Comment: Of course I could just write the code and let whatever software create the actual sequence diagram out of it. But doing that way I feel like I'm taking the lazy way. The application I'm developing isn't that big, so having a more or less complete sequence diagram beforehand - which will be edited slightly afterwards for sure - helps me to get a better overview. And I simply have to put that sequence diagram in the documentation. So it has to be as perfect as possible.

Comment: If you are doing this as part of an end of apprenticeship test, then you should be asking your boss, others in your team (if applicable) and the jury (if possible) what they'd do in this situation. This both shows a willingness to ask for help and you're more likely to get an answer that fits in with the company's approach to such things. Asking random folk on the internet for help in such a specific situation will rarely yield a good answer.

Comment: If you have an automated tool that creates sequence diagrams out of code, I doubt very much that it would bother documenting the `using` statement.  If it doesn't, that's a clue that you can omit it.  If it does, you'll know how to do it.

Comment: @DavidArno You're right, I should ask my coworkers. But that's the problem. They're less experienced in UML topics. Asking the jury is not possible, same for my boss. So I guess my way to go is this: trying to create it as good as I can, write the code and then let Visual Studio create the sequence diagram out of it. Compare both and see how good my sequence diagram was. Thanks so far!

Comment: "*Asking the jury is not possible, same for my boss*". Really, why on earth can you not ask your boss? They are utterly failing in their duty to help you develop and grow as a useful member of the team if they cannot or will not answer such questions.

Comment: Because my boss isn‘t a software developer nor has any deep knowledge of it. First persons to approach are my teammates, but as I mentioned above they‘re less experienced in UML things. Anyway, that‘s a different topic.

Comment: Diagram to help you reason about design, not code per se. Then after the fact update them. No diagram survives the first compile. Do not make it a moral dilemma because it's not. Once you must start reasoning about code - code!  Diagramming code details helps no one. Don't misunderstand; sequence diagrams are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a C# programmmer, but I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) that shows a simple example:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

Here's how I'd show this in UML:

[image]

What's key to show is that there is a temporary scope. So, it's a rare case where the "X" (end of life of an object) is used in UML sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on a lot of factors.

If you want to use the sequence diagram to generate code from it, then most tools will not understand this kind of double activation. In that sense, it is not valid.

If it is important to show the lifetime of the `CmSdkScope` object, then just a comment explaining that an activation bar corresponds to a `using()` statement is too subtle for by taste. Then I would explicitly draw the creation and destruction of the `CmSdkScope` object and possibly leave the fact that this is realized with a using statement as an implementation detail.

In most other cases, I would say that it is a perfectly understandable sequence, so I would call it valid.

Comment: This answer says what [@Furmanator answer shows.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/368210/38663) but I like the additional reasoning And, this question succinctly answers the OP question "is this diagram artifact valid?"

Answer (score 1):

You could use an *interaction frame* to represent a using block. 
They can be used to denote loops and conditionals; this is a bit different, but it lends itself well for this kind of representation, IMO.

[image: Interaction frames]

Take a look at this for more detail: [UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169507&seqNum=2)